# My Anaconda Navigator and Spyder won't launch after installing basemap

Tags: anaconda, spyder

I just installed basemap using

`conda install -c conda-forge basemap=1.0.8.dev0`

and

```
conda install -c conda-forge basemap
```

in the Anaconda prompt but after that I was not able to launch neither Spyder nor Anaconda Navigator. I tried all trick provided here in Stackoverflow but none of them working. Any advice?

Shall I re-install the entire Anaconda without loss my libraries and packages?

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) Mixing conda-forge and default packages is a really bad idea because they are compiled differently. That's the root cause of the problem you're experiencing here.

> Shall I re-install the entire Anaconda without loss my libraries and packages?

Yes, I'm afraid you have to do that because you have corrupted your installation.

> Any advice?

The solution is to create a separate conda environment to install conda-forge packages, like this

- `conda create -n basemap-env`
- `source activate basemap-env`
- `conda install -c conda-forge basemap=1.0.8.dev0 spyder`

and start Spyder from that environment.